# How to fill color in a rectangle percentage wise?

Tags: java, swing

Hi how to paint a rectangle partially filled with color ?
I need to fill this according to the percentage of value generated by program.
I am using swing for my Java GUI [image]

Comment: That's just a filled rectangle with a width less than the surrounding outlined rectangle.

Comment: You where given a link to the section from the Swing tutorial on `Custom Painting` yesterday. The tutorial shows you how to draw a rectangle. All you do is change the x value to be a percentage of the total size of the panel. Read the tutorial. Download the code and experiment with the painting code. Then if you have a problem you post your demo code that shows the problem. Show us the effort you have made!

Answer (score 0):

Are you not looking for a "Progress bar"? see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Answer (score 0):

You could simply draw the outline using `drawRect` and fill it with `fillRect`

```
g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
g.fillRect(x, y, (int)(width * percent), height);   //where percent is 0.0 - 1.0
```